# Remove Blank Line in Visual Basic on Excel Output Macro

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Creat_Txt_File()
    mydir = "d:\Test\"

    For r = 2 To 900
        Data = Cells(r, "A")
        Data1 = Cells(r, "B")
        Data2 = Cells(r, "C")
        Data3 = Cells(r, "D")
        Data4 = Cells(r, "E")
        Data5 = Cells(r, "F")
        Data6 = Cells(r, "G")
        Data7 = Cells(r, "H")

        If Data <> "" Then
            Open mydir & Data & ".txt" For Append As #1
                Write #1, Data3
            Close #1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

I'm using that code to make TXT output files. But the TXT files have blank space after the cell value.

[image]

Anyone know how to remove the blank line?

Comment: If you're expecting the cursor to appear at the end of the first line, it's because the `Write` statement automatically adds a carriage return character to each line written to the file. If you want to suppress that carriage return, add a semicolon `;` to the end of the statement. Example: `Write #1, Data3;`